# Java 8 Collection stream Collectors.toMap

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

Why this code is not compile for me?

I try to convert List to Map using stream and toMap option

```
List<CountryToPaymentMethodsDisplayRules>
   paymentMethodDisplayRulesByCountryList = 
       gatway.getCountryPaymentMethodsDisplayRulesByCountry();

Map<PaymentMethod, CountryToPaymentMethodsDisplayRules>
   countryToPaymentMethodsDisplayRulesMap = paymentMethodDisplayRulesByCountryList
       .stream()
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(type -> type.getCountryToPaymentMethodsDisplayRules().getPaymentMethod(),
                                 type -> type));

public interface PaymentMethod extends Serializable {
}

public enum PaymentMethodType implements PaymentMethod, Serializable {
}

public interface CountryToPaymentMethodsDisplayRules {
    public PaymentMethod getPaymentMethod();
}

public class CountryToPaymentMethodsDisplayRulesEntity implements CountryToPaymentMethodsDisplayRules, PersistentEntity<Long>, Serializable {
    @Type(type = "com.plimus.core.payment.PaymentMethodTypeUserType")
    @Column(name = "PAYMENT_TYPE")
    private PaymentMethod paymentMethod;
}
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Well you've provided some code (which I've reformatted for you - please read the formatting help and avoid posting until the preview shows reasonable formatting) but you haven't said in what way it doesn't work... Ideally, rewrite this as a [mcve].

Comment: I can not find method getCountryToPaymentMethodsDisplayRules. Could you provide some information about this method?

Comment: Indeed, what *is* wrong here? Does it produce an exception? Does it produce an empty map? Does it run indefinitely? We may never know!

Answer (score 7):

You just need to provide the `Collections.toMap()` method with a method reference and an identity. Try this:

```
 Map<PaymentMethod, CountryToPaymentMethodsDisplayRules>
    countryToPaymentMethodsDisplayRulesMap = paymentMethodDisplayRulesByCountryList
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(CountryToPaymentMethodsDisplayRules::getPaymentMethod,x->x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem thanks

```
Map<PaymentMethod, CountryToPaymentMethodsDisplayRules>
countryToPaymentMethodsDisplayRulesMap = paymentMethodDisplayRulesByCountryList
   .stream()
   .collect(Collectors.toMap(type -> type.getPaymentMethod(),
                             type -> type));
```

Comment: Do you really think that the finding, that calling a method that does not exist can be fixed by removing the method call, has any worth for future readers?