# Aggregate List<String> into HashMap<String, T> using Stream API

Tags: java, java-stream, aggregation, reduce, collect

I have a `MultivaluedMap` and a list of strings, and I would like to see which of those string are keys in the `MultivaluedMap`. For each of the strings that are keys in the `MultivaluedMap`, I want to construct a new `Thing` out of the value of that key, set that string as a new key in a new `HashMap<String, Thing>`, and set the new `Thing` I've created as the value for that new key in the `HashMap`.

Right now, using a vanilla `forEach`, I have the following working solution:

```
MultivaluedMap<String, String> params = uriInfo.getQueryParameters();
HashMap<String, Thing> result = new HashMap<String, Thing>();

listOfStrings.forEach( (key) -> {
    String value = params.getFirst(key);
    if (value != null && !value.isEmpty()) {
        result.put(key, new Thing(value));
    }
});
```

However, I would like to implement a functional solution to this using the Java Stream API, and have attempted a fews solution. I have the following, which looks like it should work, but it does not:

```
MultivaluedMap<String, String> params = uriInfo.getQueryParameters();

HashMap<String, Thing> result = listOfStrings
        .stream()
        .filter(params::containsKey)
        .map( e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Thing>(e, new Thing(params.getFirst(e))))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

The `Entry::getKey` and `Entry::getValue` are giving a "*Non-static method cannot be referred from a static context*". I've tried other variations of this: constructing the objects in `keyMapper` and `valueMapper` lambdas, and using reduce with an empty map as the initial value. None have worked.

How would I rewrite my first, working solution using the Java Stream API and aggregation (e.g. `collect`, `reduce`)? I have referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108734/convert-setmap-entryk-v-to-hashmapk-v) post and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42855807/java-8-collection-stream-collectors-tomap) post and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254884/collectors-tomap-keymapper-more-succinct-expression) post.

Comment: What if it's mapped to multiple values? Also, which library is `MultivaluedMap` from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine. You just need to change the return type to `Map` instead of `HashMap`. If you need it to be `HashMap` specifically, you can pass `HashMap::new` into the [factory overload](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-).

One improvement I'd make is to cut out the unnecessary `map()` operation and do the lookup in the collector:

```
Map<String, Thing> result = listOfStrings
        .stream()
        .filter(params::containsKey)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), k -> new Thing(params.getFirst(k))));
```

Comment: Can you explain what `Function.identity()` is doing in there?

Comment: @marinatedpork It's a function that returns its input. Equivalent to `k -> k`.